# Convert element into array using PrototypeJS

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, gsub

Given I have a string - `invoice[level1][level2][level3]` and I am using Prototype as Javascript framework.

How can I turn that string into an array like this `['level1', 'level2', 'level3']`

Comment: Are you parsing HTML or json?

Comment: I just need to get things done and I have no knowledge of RegEx. Yet It's an easy nut to crack for any guy who has some knowledge of RegEx.

Comment: What exactly is "element name" here? If it is a value of `name`  attribute then it is wrong according to : http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: Damn, I should have written that it's just string :) Sry for being unspecific

Comment: @c-smile - Although brackets and braces are not in the HTML4 standard they have been allowed by every browser for at least 10 years and are an essential part of passing arrays as form values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
theString.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g)
```

Example (tested in Chrome):

```
var str = 'invoice[level1][level2][level3]';
results = new Array();
str.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g).each(
  function(item){ 
    results[results.length] = item.substring(1, item.length - 1);
  }
)
-> results contains -> ["level1", "level2", "level3"]
```

Comment: Thanks! It is ironic, that at a time I have just written same line, but forgot to add "g" at the end. :)

Comment: Can you make that result would come without brackets?

Comment: Or more conveniently still, with lookahead: `str.match(/[^[]+?(?=])/g)`

Comment: @clockworkgeek: I've never really had a good handle on lookaheads/behinds, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Strip everything till the starting `[`. Remove the ending `]` and then split on `][`

```
str.substring(str.indexOf('[') + 1, str.length - 1).split('][')
```

Comment: Elegant, and avoids the processing overheard of regex. +1 for this!